# PHP Header location fails

Tags: php

I have a PHP file that connects to a MySQL database, finds the path for a file and then I use the header location to point to it. I have an issue though, sometimes instead of the path it puts /bin:/usr/bin.

What would cause it to do this?

This is my code:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/".$PATH.".mp3");
```

Comment: There is an environment variable called `PATH`, though that should not be in your variables unless you have `register_globals` set to on, which is very bad.

Comment: Is register_globals on?

Comment: I think that worked, let me try it.